# Haskell functions failing on input of "/", "\DLE", "\22925" etc

Tags: haskell

I have a few Haskell functions such as;

```
encipher :: Int -> Char -> Char
encipher 0 ch = ch
encipher k ch = lookUp (ch) (makeKey k)




normalize :: String -> String
normalize "" = ""
normalize s =  [if (isDigit x) then x else toUpper x| x <- s, x `elem` charList]
              where charList = ['a'..'z'] ++ ['A'..'Z'] ++ ['0'..'9']


encipherStr :: Int -> String -> String
encipherStr k str = [encipher k char | char <- normalize str]
```

Which all do not produce the required on the inputs : (4,"\22925"),"\DLE", (4,"\22925") repectively. The inputs are generated by an auto tester that I have to satisfy.

I honestly don't even know what the inputs mean. Apart from the first and last, possibly being Unicode characters. My question is, how do I produce the correct output for these inputs.

For example, the normalize function with removes all punctuation, but leaves integers and letters in the string, and capitalises them, returns "" when called:

```
normalize "\DLE"
```

which is incorrect according to the automarker.

Comment: `"\DLE"` is an ASCII control character called "Data Link Escape", it has the character number 16 (0x10). Is Unicode is a superset of ASCII, it also is the Unicode Character U+0010. This character is not a digit and not a letter. If the specification of normalize is to remove all such characters, returning the empty string is the correct result. So either the automarker is broken, or you misunderstood the specification. Are you sure *all* of your functions fail on that example, and not just *one* of your three functions fails? `(4, "\22925")` is not a type-correct input for `encipher`...

Comment: ... maybe you mean `(4, '\22925')`?

Comment: This depends on what your normalizer should do of course. Can you give some insight about *what* the normalization rules are?

Comment: The normalize function has to take a string as input. For example, "This is an un11Norm.alised? mESsage". It must then return a string with everything removed except for letters and numbers, and capitalise the string. In this case it would return : "THISISANUN11NORMALISEDMESSAGE"